# How to force Directory point to C:\?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've tried:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ROOT_FOLDER" />
```

but `ROOT_FOLDER` sometimes pointing to C: drive, sometimes to other drives, on different machines. How can I fix and tell it should be C drive root?

Comment: The C:\ drive may not be present on some systems since it is not required to have a C:\ drive in Windows. Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

There's a built-in Windows Installer property for this, it's called [ROOTDRIVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/rootdrive). As you can see from its description:

> ...the installer sets [ROOTDRIVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/rootdrive) to the local drive that can be written to
>   having the most free space.

If you always need it to be C, you can add a record to the Property table for this. In WiX, this is done like this:

```
<property id="ROOTDRIVE" value="C:\" />
```

Comment: The **`ROOTDRIVE`** concept can be very strange to deal with, but I wouldn't hard code its reference to **``C:\``** unless the package is for a standard operating environment (SOE) where a **``C:\``** drive is guaranteed to exist (and even then I don't like it). [Here is another answer with some intel on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561165/129130). See section on **`TARGETDIR`**.